# How to pause the thread for some time and then show the UI once user interacts, continue the thread execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have started the Thread, In that thread i am trying to connect to the server, After receiving the response, I have to update the UI with event listeners(implemented through Interface).  Here After receiving the response i need to show the popup Dialog once user clicks OK, need to continue the thread and complete the other process.

```
 class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
        ConnectionThread() {
            this.setName("ConnectionThread");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
        // Need to pause the thread for sometime, Need to do the functionality here.  
     ((Activity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
            // custom dialog
               showAlertDialog();  
               // start the thread functionality again from that position.  
 }
});
```

}

I have tried with wait() concept and also join, which are not helped as expected. Any help appreciated.

Comment: To handle something like this, you may consider extending ASyncTask.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
This will be a bit more flexible than just using the Thread class.

Comment: An unusual interaction of elements. Are you sure it has to happen this way? Why not start a loader, that fills the first selection for the user. Then, once they click, it can start another loader? What/why is the user selecting/shown in the dialog that has to be confirmed/selected?

Comment: Thanks for feedback:
My implementation already in Threads, I cant change the implementation for my feature for now.
@john The interaction is like that only. once after getting some data i need to show the popup to the user with some values and then need to wait for his interaction once done, need to continue my process.  ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [countdownlatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

```
class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        public ConnectionThread() {
            this.setName("ConnectionThread");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //update ui then
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }
                });
                countDownLatch.await();
                //start process again
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```